# Há maneira de criar programas cross platform em C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

Sei programar em C e estou agora a aprender Java, mas gostava muito de aprender C++ e eu queria saber se é possível criar programas *cross platform*, ou seja, que rodem em qualquer SO sem ter de compilar o código em cada SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sem compilar para cada plataforma não tem como. Mas praticamente não há linguagem mais portável que C++. Ela é mais que o Java, ao contrário do que o marketing diz.

O lema do Java é "write once, run everywhere", mesmo sendo uma mentira que roda em qualquer lugar e também não conta toda a verdade porque não conta que onde roda, costuma rodar mal, porque usa o mínimo denominador comum pra rodar em "todos" os lugares.

O C++ prefere o "write once, compile everywhere". Claro que tem que tomar alguns cuidados, tem situação que não escreve só uma vez de fato. Mas pelo menos roda em todos os lugares e roda bem, se o programador souber o que está fazendo. C++ não vende ilusões.

Note que normalmente não é necessário ter o sistema operacional alvo para produzir um executável para ele. Os bons compiladores de C e C++ podem produzir executáveis para outras plataformas mesmo de onde estão rodando. Claro que isso não vale para testes reais da aplicação. No mínimo terá que ter uma máquina virtual com o sistema operacional desejado se quiser testar se está tudo ok naquela plataforma. Algo que todo mundo deveria fazer, mesmo programando em Java, salvo aplicações muito simples.

Em boas aplicações, que são úteis de fato, compilar para várias plataformas não é um problema. Quem escolhe C++ normalmente quer qualidade e C++ dá tudo o que precisa para entregar esta qualidade. Exige um esforço maior, claro.

Praticamente tudo o que vale para C, vale para o C++.

## Biblioteca multi-plataforma

Cada sistema operacional tem suas peculiaridades. Sempre que estiver fazendo IO (operações de entrada e saída de dados, inclui telas, redes, etc.) pode se deparar com condições diferentes. Algumas bibliotecas podem abstrair isso e ajuda o mesmo código ser utilizado nos diversos sistemas sem ou com mínimas modificações. É o mesmo que ocorre em Java.

Mas nenhuma biblioteca fará o melhor, todas elas adotam o "mínimo denominador comum". Algumas com mais sucesso que outras. As que tentam abstrair mais acabam criando produtos ruins em todos os sistemas operacionais, embora possam eventualmente privilegiar algum específico em detrimentos dos demais. As que abstraem menos produzem melhores resultados, mas exigem que o seu código tenha partes diferenciadas para cada sistema operacional, em maior ou menor grau.

Uma das bibliotecas de GUI mais usadas que acompanha várias abstrações extras dos sistemas operacionais é a [Qt](https://www.qt.io/). Ela funciona muito bem no Windows, é considerada nativa no Linux, tem melhorado muito no mundo mobile (dispositivos *mainstream*) e tem resultado aceitável no MacOS.

Aplicações com menos recursos de IO, ou pelo menos IO mais básico como console e arquivos, são mais fáceis de escrever um código único e rodar em todas as plataformas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Corrija-me se estiver errado. Se eu quiser que alguem que tem OS X rode o meu programa criado em Windows, eu terei de compilar o meu programa no OS X para que o meu amigo possa utilizar o meu programa. É +/- isso?

Comment: Não precisa, os compiladores podem gerar códigos executáveis para outras plataformas. Claro que se você quiser testar isso na outra plataforma precisará tê-la instalada, pelo menos em uma máquina virtual. Mas isso também é verdade em Java. O único jeito de ter certeza que vai funcionar direito em todas plataformas é testar em todas elas. Se tiver coragem e confiança suficiente que testado em apenas uma plataforma (Windows, por exemplo) funcionará em todas, aí não precisa nem ver a cara do OSX, do Linux, Android, iOS, BSD, ou qq outro OS.

Comment: Ahhh ok! Agora ficou mais claro. Obrigado pela resposta foi muito útil!

Comment: Valeria a pena mencionar na sua resposta a interface gráfica, não? Se a pergunta mencionasse só C vs C++, eu não faria esse comentário. Mas como o AP diz que está aprendendo Java, uma clara vantagem que ele vai estudar lá é não ter de se preocupar com a portabilidade das interfaces de usuário. Claro que há alternativas em C++ (por exemplo, o Qt), mas vale lembrar que esse é um foco de preocupação adicional (isto é, externo à linguagem), e que também tem suas vantagens (controle da exploração de opções/otimizações nativas do gerenciador gráfico do SO, por exemplo).

Comment: @LuizVieira blz, farei. Embora praticamente já fez :)

Answer (score 4):

Existem diversas alternativas em C++, permitindo rodar o mesmo código fonte em diversas plataformas, só que nenhuma é "automática", sem ter que compilar para a plataforma final como perguntado.

É possível fazer o código ser compilado de uma máquina para diversas outras (cross-compile), mas realmente é necessário compilar para cada plataforma específica que você quiser utilizar.